# Why can't I remove new line characters from being added with Node's exec function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following to execute shell commands using Node:

```
function puts( error, stdout, stderr ) {
    stdout = sanitize( stdout ).rtrim("\n"); // remove new line
    sys.puts( stdout );
}
```

I use this library to try and remove new lines:

```
npm install validator
```

but when I do something like this:

```
exec( "ls -l", puts );
```

it puts a new line character on the end.

I'm using `Linux` so the new line should just be a `\n` right?!

How do I stop the new line from happening?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the call to sys.puts isn't what's adding the newline? Try sys.print and see what you get.

In other news, I think that sys.puts (and sys in general) have been deprecated in node.js for a while. You should probably use console.log for this kind of thing.

Comment: Nope.. tried console.log( ... ) and the same thing happens.  It's what I would normally use :s.

Comment: Both `sys.puts` (now `util.puts`) and `console.log` will append newlines. Try `{sys|util}.print` instead, as Cameron suggests. It will not append newlines.